# Raspberry Pi 4 custom kernel will not install in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: kernel, 19.10, raspberrypi

I have installed Lubuntu on Ubuntu 64-bit server. I compiled a kernel and created a deb file for image. I got a weird error when I used gdebi to install the deb file with `sudo gdebi -n linux-image-4.19.71-custom-rt24+_4.19.71-custom-rt24+-10.00.Custom_arm64.deb`.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdebi -n linux-image-4.19.71-custom-rt24+_4.19.71-custom-rt24+-10.00.Custom_arm64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.19.71-custom-rt24+.
(Reading database ... 315908 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-image-4.19.71-custom-rt24+_4.19.71-custom-rt24+-10.00.Custom_arm64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.19.71-custom-rt24+ (4.19.71-custom-rt24+-10.00.Custom) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.19.71-custom-rt24+ (4.19.71-custom-rt24+-10.00.Custom) ...
Running depmod.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.19.71-custom-rt24+ /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.71-custom-rt24+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.19.71-custom-rt24+ /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.71-custom-rt24+
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.71-custom-rt24+
Using DTB: bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
Installing /usr/lib/linux-image-4.19.71-custom-rt24+/broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb into /boot/dtbs/4.19.71-custom-rt24+/./bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
Installing new bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.
Ignoring old or unknown version 4.19.71-custom-rt24+ (latest is 5.3.0-1014-raspi2)
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.19.71-custom-rt24+ /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.71-custom-rt24+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.19.71-custom-rt24+ /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.71-custom-rt24+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-flash-kernel 4.19.71-custom-rt24+ /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.71-custom-rt24+
Using DTB: bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
Installing /usr/lib/linux-image-4.19.71-custom-rt24+/broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb into /boot/dtbs/4.19.71-custom-rt24+/./bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
Taking backup of bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.
Installing new bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.
Ignoring old or unknown version 4.19.71-custom-rt24+ (latest is 5.3.0-1014-raspi2`
```

It looks like it installs, but claims to be unknown version. How can I correct this so I can finish by installing modules and dtbs files?

Answer (score 2):

I think the install, specifically the "flash-kernel" (see the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/flash-kernel/flash-kernel.8.en.html)) tool that copies kernel images into the right place, gets upset if the kernel name doesn't end with `-raspi` or `-raspi2`

You have to use something like `make deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-raspi KDEB_PKGVERSION=$(make kernelversion)-1` when compiling.

If you look at `/usr/share/flash-kernel/db/all.db` (raspi devices start at around line 1565)

you find

```
Machine: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B
Machine: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1
Machine: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2
Machine: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
Method: pi
Kernel-Flavors: raspi raspi2
DTB-Id: bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
U-Boot-Script-Name: bootscr.rpi
Required-Packages: u-boot-tools
```

can see "Kernel-Flavors: raspi raspi2" if not matched here is viewed as unknown

So you can either compile as "-raspi" or "-raspi2" or add/edit a machine definition which should probably go in `/etc/flash-kernel/db`

flash-kernel seems to get called at the end of `update-initramfs` to copy the new kernel image into the correct place.

Comment: have edited with further information,

Comment: initially got the tool name wrong, is flash-kernel and have fixed the raspi2 typo

Comment: Excellent work, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just built and installed 6.0.1-v8+ with

```
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- bindeb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-raspi KDEB_PKGVERSION=$(make kernelversion)-1
```

on Ubuntu 22.04.1 for raspi. Still works nicely. Anyway, flash-kernel appears to be the main hurdle. Using the `--force` parameter seems to be a possible solution. You can force the install this way:

```
sudo flash-kernel --force 6.0.1-rc1-v8
```

This is to test new kernels, which are recognized as "old or unknown".

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1257218)